# Create a new array index if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say I have a String like below

```
String s1 = "test1=1&test2=2&test3=&test4=4";
```

Pls note the test3 parameter in the string S1 as it doesn't have any value

```
String [] splitS1 = s1.split("\\&");
for (int i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
    String[] params = splitS1[i].split("=");
    System.out.println("Attribute:"+params[0]+"   Value : "+params [1]);
}
```

Above code throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 because test3 in String s1 doesn't have any value so params[1] is not valid with respect to test3.

I tried doing this

```
                if(params.length == 1) {
                    params[1] = "";
                }
```

But I know that we can't extend the array. What can be done here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `split` method that takes one parameter discards trailing empty tokens.  Here, this results in `params` having only a length of one.

User the [`split` method that also takes a `limit` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), and pass a negative `limit` to ensure that you get an array with a length that matches the number of tokens actually present: 2.

```
String[] params = splitS1[i].split("=", -1);
```

Then you won't have to create another array; you'll get an array of size `2` to start with, assuming there is an `=` present.

Comment: elegant! did not know about the limit parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to test the array length:

```
String splitS1 = s1.split("\\&");
for (int i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
    String[] params = splitS1[i].split("=");
    System.out.println(
        "Attribute: " + params[0] +
        "   Value : " + (params.length < 1 ? "<no value>" : params[1]));
}
```

It might also be worth using `printf` instead of `println`:

```
System.out.printf("Attribute: %1$s%n   Value : %2$s%n",
                  params[0],
                  params.length < 1 ? "<no value>" : params[1]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class representing a parameter, with its name and value and which parses the string:

```
public final class Parameter {

    private final String name;
    private final String value;

    public Parameter(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Parameter parse(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split("=");
        String name = parts[0];
        String value = "";
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            value = parts[1];
        }
        return new Parameter(name, value);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // add more behavior if needed.
}
```

And now you can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
    Parameter param = Parameter.parse(splitS1[i]);
    System.out.println("Parameter:" + param.getName() + " = " + param.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new String array and copy the result of split into it.

```
String[] cpy = new String[2];
for(int i=0;i<cpy.length;i++){
    cpy[i] = params[i];
}
params = cpy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this

```
String s1 = "test1=1&test2=2&test3=&test4=4";
    String[] splitS1 = s1.split("\\&");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitS1.length; i++) {
        String[] params = splitS1[i].split("=");
        String[] para=new String[2];
        if(params.length==1) {
            para[0]=params[0];
            System.out.println("Attribute:"+para[0]+"   Value : "+para [1]);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Attribute:"+params[0]+"   Value : "+params [1]);

        }
    }
```

or

```
     if(params.length==1) {
            System.out.println("Attribute:"+para[0]+"   Value : "+"");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Attribute:"+params[0]+"   Value : "+params [1]);

        }
```